# The Ifxoledbc provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: informix

I have installed the "informix" client SDK in my 64bit windows 7.in the C# net ,  while i am trying to debug the datalayer project thru the unit test something retrieve the information from the database.But i am getting the this one error " The Ifxoledbc provider is not registered on the local machine " . and also i have registered the "ifxoledbc.dll" by command prompt. but is not working. And i have tested in the 32 bit machine it is working. only problem in the 64bit machine.

Comment: Your question seems incomplete, please provide proper information.
Which this one are you referring to?

Comment: Did you install the 64-bit SDK on your 64-bit machine, or also the 32-bit version?